# Google App Script, Moving row onto another sheet if date has passed

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been working on this code and doing some research the last couple of weeks and not having much luck.  I'm looking to setup a trigger that will scan Col C of dates and if the date has passed move that specific row to another sheet.

Below is where I'm currently at.

Note that I have today's date stored in cell 'O2' of the 'Contract Language' sheet.

I've gotten this code to work with text, but not with dates.

Any advise is greatly appreciated!

```
function MovetoPastShows2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Confirmed Deals'); //source sheet
  var testrange = sheet.getRange('C:C');
  var testvalue = testrange.getValues();
  var todaysheet = ss.getSheetByName('Contract Language');
  var todaycol = todaysheet.getRange('O2');
  var today = todaycol.getValues().valueOf();
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName('Confirmed (Past)'); //destination sheet
  var data = [];
  var j =[];


for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
  if ( testvalue[i] = today) {
  data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,187).getValues());
  j.push(i);
 }
 }

 csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);

  for (i=0;i<j.length;i++){
  var k = j[i]+1;
  sheet.deleteRow(k);

  if (!(i == j.length-1)) {
  j[i+1] = j[i+1]-i-1;
}
}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move Past Rows to Destination Sheet

```
function MovetoPastShows2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Confirmed Deals'); 
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var today=new Date(ss.getSheetByName('Contract Language').getRange('O2').getValue()).valueOf();
  var dsh=ss.getSheetByName('Confirmed (Past)'); 
  var d=0;
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if (new Date(vA[i][2]).valueOf()<=today) {
      dsh.appendRow(vA[i])
      sh.deleteRow(i+1-d);
      d++;
    }
  }
}
```