# Using Google Apps Script to Move Data to New Sheet After Time Delay

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am attempting to write a script that will scan a spreadsheet where one column contains date data (Column C) and if 72 hours or more have passed, move the entire row of data to a new spreadsheet.

This is the format for the date data:

```
MM/DD/YYYY H:MM:SS
```

Example:

```
12/11/2022 9:21:19
```

This is an example of the google sheet where data enters:

**SPREADSHEET 1 (Receives Incoming Data)**

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Josh | 2022-11-29 20:29:47 |
| Samantha | 2022-12-23 19:25:52 |

So based on this example, the script would move the entire second row to a new spreadsheet (since more than 72 hours have passed between the date and the current time):

**SPREADSHEET 2**

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Josh | 2022-11-29 20:29:47 |
|  |  |

My goal is to have this script "listen" for any new rows added to the google spreadsheet and automatically move rows once 72 hours have passed.

I have tried building this with excel functions but get errors where the expected number of rows and actual rows are not equal.

I am very new with google app scripts but I used the following two posts to try and piece together code but can't get it to deploy:

[Calculating difference between two dates in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545080/calculating-difference-between-two-dates-in-google-apps-script)

[Google App Script, Moving row onto another sheet if date has passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56827180/google-app-script-moving-row-onto-another-sheet-if-date-has-passed)

Is a Google App Script connected to my spreadsheet the best approach for this? Can anyone help me write the script or show me how to begin?

Comment: Yes, Google App Script can do this. Your two reference posts are in the right direction. Would you mind sharing your code here so we can just tweak the part that isn't working?

Comment: HI. "My goal is to have this script _listen" for any new rows_. That's one approach (you could use `onEdit` (read up on [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)). But `onEdit` happens in "real time" and you don't want to move the row until 72 hours have passed.  You could use an `onOpen` trigger (executes when the spreadsheet is opened), or a `time-based trigger` (run automatically every hour/whatever), or execute the script manually. The choice depends on the risks (if any) of including "72+hour" rows in your spreadsheet. Would you please outline your views.

Answer (score 1):

Move data older than 72 hours:

```
function moveOldData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//move from
  const tsh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//move to
  const shsr = 2;
  const dt = new Date();
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate());
  const  vs = sh.getRange(shsr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - shsr +1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let o  = vs.map(r => {
    if(dtv >= new Date(r[2]).valueOf() + 259,200,000) {
      return r;
    }
  }).filter(e => e);
  tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); //Source
  var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1aW8fA2pQhsefFTi2tMtmyJO6828eaQFI07sp_UEFgwI").getActiveSheet(); //Destination

  var moreThan3days = [];
  var lessThan3Days = [];

  var currentTime = new Date().getTime()

  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();

  for (i = 0; i < sourceData.length; i++) {
    var times = sourceData[i][1].getTime()
    var diffInDays = ((currentTime - times) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
    if (diffInDays > 3) {
      moreThan3days.push(sourceData[i])
    } else {
      lessThan3Days.push(sourceData[i])
    }
  }
  //Move 
  if (moreThan3days.length != 0) {
    destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, moreThan3days.length, 2).setValues(moreThan3days)
    sourceSheet.getRange(2, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow(), sourceSheet.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
  }
  //Remove from existing data
  if (lessThan3Days.length != 0) {
    sourceSheet.getRange(2, 1, lessThan3Days.length, 2).setValues(lessThan3Days);
  }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

This script checks the column B if the date is more than 3 days. Then moves the rows to another spreadsheet if it is. Otherwise it stays there.

However, there is no way for Google Apps Script to keep track of these dates since they can't hold these date values and only move them once they go past 72 hours.

What you can do is use a Time-driven trigger. This will run the script automatically according to what you setup.

- By going to **Triggers** on the left panel
- Add Trigger
- Event Source: **Time-driven**. Then the type and interval will be up to you either by hour or minute, experiment which works best for you.